# Why we get a pem file when creating a VM on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, ssh, pem

I'm recently working on creating a cloud instance on Azure. Once I created a new VM for the service I need, it always lets me download a pem file. However, it seems like I can log in to the VM through SSH without using the pem file.

Besides that, when I check the "authorized_keys" file on the new VM, it includes a public key, which is not the one on my local machine's "id_rsa.pub" file.

I'm wondering how I could log in without the public key stored in the authorized_keys file?

I think this question is related to SSH, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Why we get a pem file when creating a VM on Microsoft Azure?

Disabling password logins to SSH is a common practice for SSH hardening [[1](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/5-ssh-hardening-tips/),[2](https://linuxhandbook.com/ssh-hardening-tips/)]. The PEM file provided by default will help you achieve this.

> Besides that, when I check the "authorized_keys" file on the new VM,
> it includes a public key, which is not the one on my local machine's
> "id_rsa.pub" file

I believe you are viewing the file for another user or comparing the wrong keys.

> I'm wondering how I could log in without the public key stored in the
> authorized_keys file?

You could change the `authorized_keys` file you are referring to by modifying the `AuthorizedKeysFile` variable in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is that I could log in as `azureuser` without using the pem file given by Azure or password. 

I did not change the user from `azureuser` to another one. So I think the public key in `authorized_keys` should be the same as `id_rsa.pub`. But I do not know why it shows different.

Comment: Besides that, I found that I could only login as `azureuser` when using ssh. However, I could use `sudo` to change to another one after that.